# Ensuring full connectivity

Tags: graph-theory

I have a graph where each element belongs to one of the two groups $A$ and $B$. An element of group $A$ can have link only with elements from $B$ and vice-versa. I want to ensure the full connectivity of the graph. Now, let $A_i$ denote the set of neighbors of the $i^{th}$ element of A and $B_i$ denote the set of neighbors of the $i^{th}$ element of B. Then, to ensure the full connectivity of the graph, I came up with the following two conditions:

- $\bigcup_i A_i = B$
- $|A_i \cap A_k| > 1$, for all $k \neq i$ where $|\cdot|$ denotes the cardinality of the set.

I wanted to know if these conditions are sufficient to ensure the full connectivity of the graph (or if you have suggestions of other conditions).

Comment: Don't you just mean that the graph is bipartite?

Comment: @Math1000: I'm not quite familiar with the graph theory terminology. But from the definition I've read on Wikipedia, it should be. I'm looking to characterize the graph through the sets $A_i$ and $B_i$ to ensure it fulfills the definition given above.